# Can LUIS export a KB in Firefox?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Anyone know how to get the latest version of the LUIS UI to export a KB in Firefox? It seems to be using some form of 'clever' JavaScript that does not like Firefox. I can download in Edge but Firefox seems to go through the motions and I get the notification saying it's done from LUIS but no sign of the file.

Comment: Silly question here, do you have popup windows blocked on Firefox?

Comment: I was able to repro your steps on Firefox. It looks like this is a LUIS UI bug, and I notified the LUIS team about it. Hopefully a fix will be released soon. Thanks for letting the community know!

Comment: Hi @pkr2000, it looks like the fix has been deployed. Hopefully Firefox works well when exporting the app; please let me know if you're experiencing problems.

Comment: Thanks, now I get a popup :)

Comment: It looks like there has been an update to the UI which makes this broken with firefox (v. 66.0.4 here) again. @Corina how did you notify them back then?

Comment: I'm happy to pass along your bug report. Please feel free to email me (check my profile) and I can send the message along. Be sure to include any console errors and screenshots that can help identify the issue. Unfortunately my coworker who I would pass this along to is gone for the day, but they'll see my email on Monday.

Comment: @Corina sent you a mail. thanks! :)

Comment: Unfortunately no answer so far. @Corina if you could step in once more? I sent a follow-up mail on 19/07/19, but never got an answer.

Comment: @A.Blesius it looks like back in May my colleague replied to you, and as far as I can tell you respond. If there's further correspondence with you two, I would follow up with him.

Comment: Yes, there was an answer in May, but after my reply in July, they haven't got back to me. I can work around this using Chromium, but it's a bit silly to open a different browser just to download a JSON file. I'd be happy to provide more info, doing anything I can to debug, but I'd need support with that. I can't do it on my own.

Comment: @A.Blesius - When I export as JSON, the JSON opens up in a new Firefox page. Does that not happen for you?

Comment: Also Firefox 'corrupts' the JSON encoding, I'm guessing because it renders it to the page rather than just downloading it.

Comment: @KyleDelaney nope, that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue, so you will need to open a bug in the [feedback forum](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/551524-luis) and provide more details about how to reproduce the issue.